# How to define a global list in python

Tags: python

I have two methods that should write to the same list.

```
class MySpider():

    def parse_post(self, response):
        commentList = []
        ...  
        commentList.append(someData)

    def parse_comments(self, response):
        commentList = []
        ...  
        commentList.append(someData)
```

In this code there are two commentList lists but I need a single list where I can append data. I want to access this list in any method of this class. I tried with

```
class MySpider():

    commentNum = []

    def parse_post(self, response):
        ...  
        commentList.append(someData)

    def parse_comments(self, response):
        ...  
        commentList.append(someData)
```

But this gives me an error `global name commentList is not defined`. Any ideas how to have a single list that can be accessed in all methods in that class?

Comment: You're saying "array" in the text, but your code has it right: it's a list.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Terminology: "global" refers to a module-level variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to simply refer to the variable by its full name (`MySpider.commentList`):

```
class MySpider(object):

    commentList = []

    def parse_post(self, response):
        ...  
        MySpider.commentList.append(someData)

    def parse_comments(self, response):
        ...  
        MySpider.commentList.append(someData)
```

**This way all instances of `MySpider` will share the same variable**.

If you might have multiple instances of `MySpider`, and want each instance to have its own `commentList`, then simply create it in the constructor and refer to it as `self.commentList`:

```
class MySpider(object):

    def __init__(self):    
        self.commentList = []

    def parse_post(self, response):
        ...  
        self.commentList.append(someData)

    def parse_comments(self, response):
        ...  
        self.commentList.append(someData)
```

If both versions would work in your case, I'd suggest using the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Scrapy. If the list is part of an Item, I usually pass that item to another callback using [meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) parameter of a Request/Response object .

Answer (score 1):

Just do `self.commentList.append(someData)`

(Note that normal Python style is to use `comment_list` and `some_data`, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Just make it a instance attribute:

```
class MySpider(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.comment_list = []
    def parse_post(self, response):
        ...  
        self.comment_list.append(someData)
```

The instance (`self` in python by convention, `this` in java e.g.) is explicit in python.

If you initialize your array outside methods (like in your 2nd listing), you make it a class attribute (i.e. static one), that is "global" to all instances, and it should be referenced using the full name `MySpider.comment_list` or `type(self).comment_list` if you want to avoid the class name (e.g. for inheritance). Due to the lookup of attributes, `self.comment_list` will also work (if the attribute is not found at instance level, the class is looked for) but the distinction is less obvious ("explicit is better than implicit").